# Custom Default/Index route when page initalizationm

Tags: html-framework-7

i am having a problem dealing with first page load in my app. in my routes, i set home.html as my default route, but its not included in my view.router lists. and how to set default route or index route with a different name (not index.html) e.g home.html, dashboard.html

```
{
      path: '/',
      url: '/home.html',
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard/',
      url: '/dashboard.html',
    },
```

when first load, the home.html is not included in the lists of routers. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will answer you but you need to change in your config file the defaultl HTML page to be loaded

[image]

Comment: where is that  config file located?

Comment: In the same levels as your www folder